# Identification office plant, fake or real?

Tags: identification, office-gardening

There is a huge pot with a plant in it in the hall way of our company. Nobody knows what it is and if it's fake or not (some photos can be seen below). We never give it water as well and it doesn't seem he needs it.

If it's not fake, what kind of plant is it and does it need some kind of care?

The leaves feel cardboard-ish. Maybe that's some information you need to identify this plant.

[image: Hall way plant]

[image: Hall way plant]

Comment: not a duplicate, this specimen is much larger, and could be a sub-specimen of plants.

Comment: @Gerwin  It is a group of bromeliads glued to a piece of decorative wood. That's why it looks larger.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bromeliad, likely a variety of Aechmea Fasciata.  See [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3519/what-is-this-houseplant/3521#3521) for details.