# Houseplant ident

Tags: identification, houseplants

Does anyone recognise this plant? It was given to me by my flatmate to divide in 3, and it would be nice to know its name. Couldn't find it hessayons plant spotter
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is *Aechmea fasciata*, a bromeliad, commonly known as Urn Plant.It produces a central pink flower spike, but once that dies down, the leaves surrounding it sometimes die back. But secondary growths, or pups, are produced,and that seems to be what's happened with this one, although the central part of the plant also looks healthy. They can be divided from the main plant, but its probably easier to decant it from its pot to do so - when you cut or separate the pup away from the parent plant, make sure it has some good roots attached and pot up separately. Afterwards, replace the mother plant and fill in the gaps in the soil with fresh potting soil. Bit more info here https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/urn-plant.html

Comment: also see here https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/3521/499

Comment: The pink flower looks good for months ; the plant is hurt by freezing temperatures; mosquitoes will grow in the water it holds.